# How to update column after time end in other in postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have table with column id,open,close .Open and close are time-stamp.I want auto update close when time ends from Open column.
eg.Suppose in Open timestamp is "2014-12-23 17:50:39.049" when this particular comes then update close column with current timestamp.

Comment: use `cron job` or a stored `procedure`

Comment: @BhargavModi You have to invoke a function (PostgreSQL doesn't have true "stored procedures", but its functions are pretty close to as good) from something. Like, as you pointed out, a cron job. It doesn't have time-based procedures.

Comment: @CraigRinger right, cron or any kind of interval service from `program` like in `java`

Comment: Thanks @BhargavModi,actually I am looking solution for this using DB.I don't think stored procedure is good option for this problem.

Comment: first show us what hae you tried up till now, then we can provide you a help.

Comment: A cron jod that calls `psql --file=some_file.sql`. Simple `UPDATE` query in `some_file.sql`. Thats it.

Comment: I tried with quartz using java.This is perfect lib for me.but I am looking solution at DB end.but I am not able start....